# Entity is null for most of the requests - LUIS

Tags: artificial-intelligence, botframework, azure-language-understanding

Bot Framework version - 3.11.0

I have added intents as below in LUIS:

[image: Intents added in LUIS]

Whenever I call the API as [here](https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/ac6598a5-44be-4e34-a0d0-ab07ca7e3887?subscription-key=f6e29bea80ac486ab070e7be67475f1e&spellCheck=true&verbose=true&timezoneOffset=0&q=who%20knows%20site?) I get entities empty. It works randomly like this [query](https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/ac6598a5-44be-4e34-a0d0-ab07ca7e3887?subscription-key=f6e29bea80ac486ab070e7be67475f1e&spellCheck=true&verbose=true&timezoneOffset=0&q=who%20knows%20sitecore) works

Am I missing anything? What might be the reason LUIS can able to find the entity in one case than other, as both are using same utterance and intent?

Comment: I had a similar case where items at the end of a sentence followed by question mark or other symbols were not detected. If you test your 1st sample without "?" It is detected, so you could remove it before calling LUIS

Answer (score 0):

You are using very few utterances. You should use at least 12 and with a varied structure, not just "Who know..." "Who knows..." etc. Also for the other intents you need to add enough utterances as well.

Answer (score 0):

The more intents you can add here it will be better. And after adding the intents and entities please make sure you are training/re-training the bot. Many times LUIS has a tendency to skip a trained model altogether. Also please do publish the model for a better efficiency.